# How to disable AJAX sending method in Contact Form 7 and keep other JS options like validation

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to use `wpcf7_form_action_url` filter and change action in form.
To be able to do this, I need to disable the AJAX which is used when submitting the form

`define('WPCF7_LOAD_JS', false)` is not a solution because `WPCF7 AJAX` is packaged into an **entire** JS flag - so this will also turn off JS validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if WPCF7_LOAD_JS JS is disabled, it will take the input to the server, validate and return to the form and show the errors. So, I think you not losing any validation functionality when submitting the form.

Comment: disabling `WPCF7_LOAD_JS` doesn't disable form validation.

Comment: @kanlukasz I have tried in my local server and verification working fine after disabled WPCF7_LOAD_JS please check screenshot - http://prntscr.com/tltorb. So, I suggest that another JS or any other plugins maybe conflict with WPCF7

Comment: Okay, you are right! I found out what the problem is - if I use `wpcf7_form_action_url`, the validation does not work so here is a problem. Thanks for the confirmation though